# What are the differences between GitHub Actions and other CI tools like Jenkins?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, devops, github-actions

GitHub announced an upcoming feature, [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions).

I'm positive on the benefits of CI tools like Jenkins for automatic building or testing, which GitHub Actions is aimed to be used for in the future.

Having a repository on GitHub and using an external CI tool has the huge benefit of allowing to move the repository to another Git repository platform (or even local) without rewriting of the whole CI process. With GitHub Actions, you're more or less tied to the GitHub ecosystem.

I assume the integration of GitHub's Actions will be more fluent in the *native* environment, but are there any other advantages or disadvantages besides that?

Comment: CI tools like Jenkins provide a lot of plugins out of the box to integrate with various services or the ability to write your own plugins to do what you want. SCM pipeline functionality for ex. Bitbucket pipelines or Github Actions may be good for quick build-test-deploy but dont think they offer much flexibility or is as easy as working with Jenkins to integrate, customize etc

Comment: IMO, since Github Actions run on Docker containers, I don't think that they are much tied to the Github ecosystem, except for the workflow file.

Comment: In addition to what @Pavitra said, _because_ it runs on Docker containers, there are some things that aren't as easy to do as with other CI tools. Namely if a base image doesn't exist for whatever you're doing.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've been working with GitHub actions full time for a couple of months now.

It's still early days (June 2019), but here's my list:

#### Advantages:

1. GitHub actions are just consecutive docker runs. Very easy to reason about and debug. 
   Reproducing the build environment for [container-based Travis is
   possible](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/running-build-in-debug-mode/),
   but more difficult.
   On GitHub actions it's just a `docker build` `docker run` away.
2. The individual *actions* in a *workflow* are isolated by default.
   You can use a completely different computing environment for, say, compilation and testing.
   Travis CI (and I think other "traditional" CI) would run all "stages" (~ actions) in the same computing environment.
   Again, GitHub actions are much easier to reason about and debug.
3. The `main.workflow` spec (a subset of the HCL and really just a directed acyclic graph) is [open source](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/running-build-in-debug-mode/).
   The whole thing is a pretty thin wrapper around Docker anyway, so platform lock-in is arguably minimal.
4. There are *already* open-source reimplementations of GitHub actions, such as [act](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/running-build-in-debug-mode/) for local testing.
5. You have ready access to the GitHub API with (somewhat limited) authentication out of the box.
6. There *might* be a vibrant community (marketplace?) where people can share actions.
   For example, I'm reusing deploy actions build by different people in different ecosystems.
7. A directed acyclic graph (DAG) and the visual editor for `main.workflow`s is perhaps a good way to model CI/CD in particular and workflows in general.
   Takes some getting used to, but generalises well.
8. GitHub actions can do a whole lot more than just CI! You've got basically the whole API at your fingertips as inputs and outputs.

#### Disadvantages:

GitHub actions (still?) has sometimes surprisingly foundational limitations at this point (june 2019).

1. No native caching.
   You get *image* and *layer caching* (it's [complicated](https://r-lib.github.io/ghactions/articles/performance.html)), but nothing else.
   For build artefacts, you have to roll your own cache (via AWS, Azure, etc. ...), which can be a lot of work. (You can see a [hacky setup here](https://github.com/r-lib/ghactions/blob/master/.github/main.workflow).
2. Surprisingly, **no support for pull requests from forks**.
   It's again a bit [complicated](https://github.com/r-lib/ghactions/issues/262), and understandable from a security standpoint, but it's currently not possible to run actions a) against the secrets of the receiving repo of a fork PR (base), and/or b) against the *would-be* merge result of a fork PR (that's what travis does).
   For a workflow that involves forks, that makes GitHub actions largely unuseable as CI/CD tool.
3. Single platform, it's just whatever you can run inside docker, so some Linux distro. That seems unlikely to change, but might be an acceptable limitation.
   You can always add an action to call other cross-platfrom CI/CD services.
4. The documentation is still pretty sparse. 
   Not much in the way of best practices or scaffolding.
5. The quality and breadth of published GitHub actions (at least on the marketplace) is still pretty low / limited. 
   We'll see whether that takes off.
6. No great way to unit-test actions. (I [hacked](https://github.com/r-lib/ghactions/tree/master/actions/document) something together, but I'm not too sure about it).

Comment: You might want to update this answer as Github Actions now support three platforms, YAML syntax, etc.

Answer (score 7):

> Having a repository on GitHub and using an external CI tool has the huge benefit of allowing to move the repository to another Git repository platform (or even local) without rewriting of the whole CI process.
>   With GitHub Actions, you're more or less tied to the GitHub ecosystem.

Yes, and starting November 2019, slightly less so:

See [Joe Bourne](https://github.com/thejoebourneidentity)'s annoucement "[**Self-hosted runners for GitHub Actions is now in beta**](https://github.blog/2019-11-05-self-hosted-runners-for-github-actions-is-now-in-beta/)".

You can have self-hosted runners, which means:

> - **Your environment, your tools**,
> - **Any size machine or configuration**,
> - **Secure access and networking**,
> - **Large workload support**.
>
> To support using self-hosted runners in your workflows, we’ve expanded the experience of using the `runs-on` key.
>   When registering your self-hosted runners, they’re each given a read-only label self-hosted which you can use with `runs-on`.
>   Here’s an example:
>
> ```
> # Use Any available Self-hosted runners connected to repo
> runs-on: self-hosted
> ```

See the documentation at "[**Hosting your own runners**](https://help.github.com/en/github/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/hosting-your-own-runners)".